# Spring boot - google oauth2, store refresh token in database

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-security, spring-security-oauth2, google-oauth

i'm trying to get the refresh token from the user logged in my system, and store it in a database. So a different system in my ecosystem can access the stored refresh token, generate an access token with it and use the google calendar api with the user credentials.

So far i have managed to do the login with

```
@Configuration
public class AppConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {
    @Autowired
    private ClientRegistrationRepository clientRegistrationRepository;

    @Override
    public void configure(HttpSecurity httpSecurity) throws Exception {
        httpSecurity
                .authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers("/**").authenticated()
                .anyRequest().permitAll()
                .and()
                .oauth2Login()
                .authorizationEndpoint()
                .authorizationRequestResolver(new CustomAuthorizationRequestResolver(
                        this.clientRegistrationRepository))
                .and()
                .and()
                .rememberMe();
    }
}
```

And

```
public class CustomAuthorizationRequestResolver implements OAuth2AuthorizationRequestResolver {
    private final OAuth2AuthorizationRequestResolver defaultAuthorizationRequestResolver;

    public CustomAuthorizationRequestResolver(
            ClientRegistrationRepository clientRegistrationRepository) {

        this.defaultAuthorizationRequestResolver =
                new DefaultOAuth2AuthorizationRequestResolver(
                        clientRegistrationRepository, "/oauth2/authorization");
    }

    @Override
    public OAuth2AuthorizationRequest resolve(HttpServletRequest request) {
        OAuth2AuthorizationRequest authorizationRequest =
                this.defaultAuthorizationRequestResolver.resolve(request);

        return authorizationRequest != null ?
        customAuthorizationRequest(authorizationRequest) :
        null;
    }

    @Override
    public OAuth2AuthorizationRequest resolve(
            HttpServletRequest request, String clientRegistrationId) {

        OAuth2AuthorizationRequest authorizationRequest =
                this.defaultAuthorizationRequestResolver.resolve(
                        request, clientRegistrationId);

        return authorizationRequest != null ?
        customAuthorizationRequest(authorizationRequest) :
        null;
    }

    private OAuth2AuthorizationRequest customAuthorizationRequest(
            OAuth2AuthorizationRequest authorizationRequest) {

        Map<String, Object> additionalParameters = new LinkedHashMap<>(authorizationRequest.getAdditionalParameters());
        additionalParameters.put("access_type", "offline");

        return OAuth2AuthorizationRequest.from(authorizationRequest)
                .additionalParameters(additionalParameters)
                .build();
    }

}
```

how and where can i access the refresh token of the logged user?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I answered a similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61362807/6469095), but it is in kotlin, so I'll add a java version for you.

These are two approaches to get the refresh token (or rather `OAuth2AuthorizedClient`, from which you can get the refresh token). Which one you use depend on your needs.

1. Inject and `OAuth2AuthorizedClient` representing the requesting user into an endpoint method:

```java
@GetMapping("/foo")
void foo(@RegisteredOAuth2AuthorizedClient("google") OAuth2AuthorizedClient user) {
    OAuth2RefreshToken refreshToken = user.getRefreshToken();
}
```

2. Outside the context of a request, you can inject `OAuth2AuthorizedClientService` into a managed component, and get the needed `OAuth2AuthorizedClient` instance with the client registration id and principal name:

```java
@Autowired
private OAuth2AuthorizedClientService clientService;

public void foo() {
    OAuth2AuthorizedClient user = clientService.loadAuthorizedClient("google", "principal-name");
    OAuth2RefreshToken refreshToken = user.getRefreshToken();
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot Stav Shamir, this was the exact thing i needed, everything running smooth