# How do I set the scope to call the Google People API in Java?

Tags: oauth-2.0, google-api, google-people-api

I am using the following code. I have a valid accessToken. How can I set the scope to email,profile on the Credential? I am using OAuth2 for authorization.

```
        static final String APPLICATION_NAME = "calendar-service";
        static final JsonFactory JSON_FACTORY = JacksonFactory.getDefaultInstance();

        Credential credential = new 
 Credential(BearerToken.authorizationHeaderAccessMethod()).setAccessToken(accessToken);
        // Build a new authorized API client service.
        final NetHttpTransport HTTP_TRANSPORT = GoogleNetHttpTransport.newTrustedTransport();
    
        PeopleService service = new PeopleService.Builder(HTTP_TRANSPORT, JSON_FACTORY, credential)
                .setApplicationName(APPLICATION_NAME)
                .build();

        ListConnectionsResponse response = service.people().connections()
                .list("people/me")
                .setPersonFields("names,emailAddresses")
                .execute();
        
        List<Person> connections = response.getConnections();
        if (connections != null && connections.size() > 0) {
            for (Person person : connections) {
                List<Name> names = person.getNames();
                if (names != null && names.size() > 0) {
                    System.out.println("Name: " + person.getNames().get(0)
                            .getDisplayName());
                } else {
                    System.out.println("No names available for connection.");
                }
            }
        } else {
            System.out.println("No connections found.");
        }
        
        return connections.get(0);
```

I am getting the following error:

```
GET https://people.googleapis.com/v1/people/me/connections?personFields=names,emailAddresses
{
  "code" : 403,
  "errors" : [ {
    "domain" : "global",
    "message" : "Insufficient Permission",
    "reason" : "insufficientPermissions"
  } ],
  "message" : "Request had insufficient authentication scopes.",
  "status" : "PERMISSION_DENIED"
}] with root cause

com.google.api.client.googleapis.json.GoogleJsonResponseException: 403 Forbidden
```

Here is my application.properties:

```
spring.security.oauth2.client.registration.google.clientId=XYZ456.apps.googleusercontent.com
spring.security.oauth2.client.registration.google.clientSecret=ABC123
spring.security.oauth2.client.registration.google.redirectUri={baseUrl}/oauth2/callback/{registrationId}
spring.security.oauth2.client.registration.google.scope=email,profile
```

Please advise.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### There is a [quickstart](https://developers.google.com/people/quickstart/java) for using People API with Java

It contains the following line:

```
private static final List<String> SCOPES = Arrays.asList(PeopleServiceScopes.CONTACTS_READONLY);
```

This is the line where you can change your scope to a ddiferent one if desired, or add additional scopes.

To know which scopes you need, go onto the documentation page for the [method you use](https://developers.google.com/people/api/rest/v1/people.connections/list).

[image]

IMPORTANT

Each time you change the scopes, you need to delete the token file from your machine, so that new authorization flow willbe triggered.

Comment: Thank you for the information, especially about deleting the token file when I change the scope. I tried deleting the token file and rerunning the application and did not have any luck. Also, the quick start is for a standalone application.  I have a ClientRegistration Spring OAuth2 object and know there is a setScope on it; however, am not sure how to pass that through to the PeopleService object's Builder method.

Comment: I do not work with Spring Boot, however if you pass to your application an already existing access token -  this token is generated based on the provided scopes - so the scopes must be given before the creation of this token. Where do you get the token from? See if [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61362807/11599789) is useful.